# React — dynamic list <li>'s not accessible in doc.ready, but <ul> is?

Tags: reactjs

I built a list using a json object loaded into the state.

The li items seem to be inaccessible from the document.ready function. i.e. binding a click function to the li's doesn't work.

However, I can bind to the parent UL which I find odd.

**Here is my list component:**

```js
import React from 'react';

var Albums = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <ul id="frames_list">
        {this.props.frames.map(function(frames){
          return (
            <li key={frames.frameId}>
              <Link to="/frames" >{frames.frameName}</Link>
            </li>
          )
        }.bind(this))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = Albums;
```

**Here is my doc.ready code:**

```js
$('#frames_list li').click(function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

**Here is the parent component setting state:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import SideNavHeader from './SideNavHeader';
import SideNavAccordionMenu from './SideNavAccordionMenu';
import SideNavFooter from './SideNavFooter';

var framesData, albumsData, channelsData;

$.getJSON("/json/frames.json", function(frames){
    framesData = frames;
});
$.getJSON("/json/albums.json", function(albums){
    albumsData = albums;
});
$.getJSON("/json/channels.json", function(channels){
    channelsData = channels;
});

var SideNav = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      frames: [],
      albums: [],
      channels: []
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    var framesList = [], albumsList = [], channelsList = [];
    // Fake an AJAX request with a setTimeout function
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      framesList=framesData.frames;
      albumsList=albumsData.albums;
      channelsList=channelsData.channels;
      // Set state when the request completes
      this.setState({
        frames: framesList,
        albums: albumsList,
        channels: channelsList
      });
    }.bind(this), 10);
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <SideNavHeader />
        <SideNavAccordionMenu frames={this.state.frames} albums={this.state.albums} channels={this.state.channels} />
        <SideNavFooter />
      </section>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = SideNav;
```

Comment: How do you load the `frames` list? My guess is that it's not loaded at document ready.

Comment: The list is nside a component that is inside the main App component. The list data being passed as state. What's the React equivalent of doc.ready? I tried it i in componentDidMount and that didn't work.

Comment: Show the code that sets the `frames` as state. In React `componentDidMount` at the top level component is the closes equivalent to document ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to be attaching click listeners out in your DOM. React is going to be doing stuff to your DOM, including destroying nodes and creating new ones. This may break your listeners, which are tied to specific nodes, which might go away.

In this case, you probably want to use React's built in `onClick` attribute in JSX, as seen [in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#a-simple-example).

Try something like:

```js
import React from 'react';

var Albums = React.createClass({
  handleClick(event) {
    console.log('li was clicked');
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <ul id="frames_list">
        {this.props.frames.map(function(frames){
          return (
            <li key={frames.frameId} onClick={this.handleClick}>
              <Link to="/frames" >{frames.frameName}</Link>
            </li>
          )
        }.bind(this))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = Albums;
```

As an aside, for clarity, I personally like break out the mapping through items into its own function:

```js
import React from 'react';

var Albums = React.createClass({
  handleClick(event) {
    console.log('li was clicked');
  },

  renderFrames() {
    return this.props.frames.map(frame => {
      return (
        <li key={frame.frameId} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <Link to="/frames" >{frame.frameName}</Link>
        </li>
      );
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <ul id="frames_list">
        {this.renderFrames()}
      </ul>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = Albums;
```

Comment: This works... now, instead of console.log I am running a function and trying to send 'this' ... so, like ... toggleActiveMenuItem(this); where that toggle function is in my doc ready.  Should I move that toggle function inside the component also?

Comment: Yeah, you'll want your toggle inside React as well. Maybe your `Albums` component has an internal state called `activeFrame` which you can set from `handleClick`.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use jquery event listener, you have to bind your click event in ComponentDidMount function (in your Albums component)